# Rope with pieces of white cloth - What is it?

Tags: culture

Often when holy places or other things that are spiritual are shown, this kind of rope with white zigzag attachments appears all the time. So far I have seen it in *From the New World*, 
*Yuki Yuna*, *Monogatari* and *Your Name*, but there are probably more.

It looks like this:

[image: rope with white stuff]

**What is it?**

The name of it is probably all I need to find out more, but it is never mentioned.

Comment: @Memor-X Thank you, just what I needed. Finding that question without anything to search for is difficult. **Shide** and  **Shimenawa** for confused people in the future.